# Bound on Gamma Function

Tags: gamma-function

Prove that $\Gamma(x)\geq x-1$ for $x \geq 3$.

We have defined $\Gamma(x)=\int _{0}^{\infty}t^{x-1}e^{-t}dt$, where $x>0$.

This is a review problem for an exam please give a full complete solution.

Thanks.

Update: I have completed a proof by induction and will post it later.

Comment: Integrating by parts $x\Gamma(x) = \, ?$

Comment: @user1952009 I don't really see how this would be helpful for the bound I am trying to show. Can you please explain this?

Comment: @user1952009 I have a theorem that states $x\Gamma (x) = \Gamma (x+1)$

Answer (score 1):

By the [Bohr-Mollerup characterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem) of the $\Gamma$ function, or from the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality applied to the integral representation, we have that $\Gamma(x)$ is a log-convex function on $\mathbb{R}^+$. Since $\Gamma(x)$ is positive for $x>0$, $\Gamma(x)$ is convex on $\mathbb{R}^+$ and

$$ \Gamma(x)\geq \Gamma'(3)(x-3)+\Gamma(3) $$
holds for any $x\in\mathbb{R}^+$. We have $\Gamma'(3)=3-2\gamma>1$, hence the given inequality is trivial.

In order to show that $0<\gamma<1$, it is enough to recall that
$$ \gamma=\sum_{n\geq 1}\left[\frac{1}{n}-\log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\right] $$
and that $x-\log(1+x)$ is bounded between $(1-\log(2))\,x^2$ and $\frac{1}{2}x^2$ on $(0,1)$.

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Prove that $\ds{\Gamma\pars{x} \geq x - 1}$ for $\ds{x \geq 3}$. $\bbox[15px,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{\mbox{It's}\ sufficient\ \mbox{to prove that}\ \Gamma\pars{x} \geq 1\ \mbox{for}\ x \geq 2}}$.

\begin{align}
\Gamma\pars{x} & =
\int_{0}^{\infty}t^{x - 1}\expo{-t}\,\dd t =
1 + \pars{x - 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}{t^{x - 1} - t \over x - 2}\expo{-t}\,\dd t
\end{align}

> For $\ds{x > 2\,,\ \exists\ \xi}$ such that $\ds{2 < \xi < x}$ and
>   $\ds{{t^{x - 1} - t \over x - 2} = t^{\xi - 1}\ln\pars{t} \geq t\ln\pars{t}}$

\begin{align}
\left.\vphantom{\Large A}\Gamma\pars{x}\,\right\vert_{\large\ x\ \geq\ 2}\ &\,\,\, {\large \geq}\,\,\,
1 + \pars{x - 2}\int_{0}^{\infty}t\ln\pars{t}\expo{-t}\,\dd t =
1 + \pars{x - 2}\pars{1 - \gamma}\
\bbox[10px,#ffe,border:1px dotted navy]{\ds{\geq 1}}
\end{align}